# Contraction of vertex-labeled graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given is a connected, unweighted and undirected Graph $G$ with two different kind of nodes, called red and blue. $G$ shall be simplified by following contraction rule:

> Each pair of red nodes is connected by a single edge if there is at least one path between them that passes only blue nodes. All blue nodes on paths between these red nodes are removed.

Is this a common problem in graph theory? How could edge contraction be performed effectively?

**Example:**

The vertices and edges of $G$ are:

$G_{red}=[1,4,6,10]\\
G_{blue}=[2,3,5,7,8,9,11]\\
G_{edge}=[(1,2),(1,4),(2,3),(3,6),(4,5),(4,7),(5,6),(6,9),(7,8),(8,9),(8,10),(10,11)]$

The contracted graph is:

$H_{red}=G_{red}\\
H_{blue}=[11]\\
H_{edge}=[(1,4),(1,6),(4,6),(4,10),(10,11)]$

[image]

**Edit**

The solution is given by an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4619600/737314) to an almost identical problem.

Comment: Why does $H$ still contain node $11$?

Comment: Is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619570/algorithm-to-create-approximate-or-simplified-graph/4619600#4619600) asking the same thing you are?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Because concerning OP node 11 does not lay on a path between two red nodes that consists purely of blue nodes. The linked post is similar and could be used to solve this problem. The OP has now a link.